# Protractor passing all tests as success without doing them

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor

Trying to run my tests with protractor I encounter a huge problem i can't explain or resolve.

When i run the tests, Protractor simply ignore all the tests and consider it has been done with success.

This is what i get as a report:

```
[16:32:02] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[16:32:02] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:32:02] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.0.33:54345/wd/hub
problem trying to remove a folder
Started
....................................

36 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.249 seconds
[16:32:15] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[16:32:15] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[16:32:15] I/launcher - chromeANY #01 passed
```

Usually tests should take around 15 minutes.

I'm using grunt-protractor-runner to run my tests.

My config is :

```
Windows 10
grunt: 1.0.1
grunt-protractor-runner: 3.2.0
selenium-webdriver: 3.0.0
protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter: 0.0.5
```

My conf file is :

```
'use strict';

var env = require('./environment.js');
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

// conf.js
exports.config = {

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'version': 'ANY'
  },

  specs: [
    'specs/01-basic.js',
    'specs/02-login.js',
    'specs/03-dmp.js',
    'specs/04-cmp.js',
    'specs/05-account.js'
  ],

  suites: {
    basic: 'specs/01-basic.js',
    login: 'specs/02-login.js',
    dmp: 'specs/03-dmp.js',
    cmp: 'specs/04-cmp.js',
    account: 'specs/05-account.js'
  },

  baseUrl: env.baseUrl + '/#/',

  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
        savePath: 'report/html',
        screenshotsFolder: 'images/',
        takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
        consolidate: true,
        consolidateAll: true
      })
    );
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.driver.get(env.baseUrl + '/#/login');
    element(by.model('user.Username')).sendKeys(env.login);
    element(by.model('user.Password')).sendKeys(env.mdp);
    element(by.id('loginSubmit')).click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
  }

};
```

Thank you !

Comment: Show the code, add more information.

Comment: can you post the conf.js file code?